# Rule-based colour of diagram bars in map

Tags: qgis, diagram

I have 80 sites with percentage of landmanagement and individual numbers of beetles.

I would like to visualise the number of individuals with a diagram (histogram, bar length, see below left diagram) and at the same time the percentage of management by colour (e.g. light blue 0% dark blue 100%, see scale below, right side).

Is there a way to combine these two by e.g. set a rule-based colour in the diagrams? I tried by adding attributes, but then I got more bars. I just want to adjust the colour of the individual numbers using the attribute percentage of management.

[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: Please provide a screenshot of what you're talking about, as well as what you tried so far.

Comment: o.k. I edited the question

Comment: Cartographically speaking ... your bars are actively prohibiting the viewer from understanding the map. It would be way easier to understand your data if you used points in order to display the location, controlled their colour by graduated symbology and labelled them with the number of beetles.

Answer (score 2):

To do this you need to set the fill colour of the boxes using an expression:

[image]

Then you need to use the `color_ramp()` function to choose a colour ramp that you like (e.g. 'Blues') and use your attribute to pick a position along that colour ramp, positions along colour ramps range from 0 to 1. So first you will have to use a function to convert your attribute (percent of management, I'm going to call this "management_percent" in the expression) to a 0 to 1 scale. So, with that, use this expression:

`ramp_color('Blues', scale_linear("management_percent", 0, 100, 0, 1))`

Comment: Alternatively one could run something like `ramp_color('Blues',"management_percent"/100)`. Or does the `scale_linear` do something relevant for the expression besides normalizing it?

Comment: @Erik in the case of this particular question `"management_percent"/100` would work fine because it is a value between 0 and 100 (assuming OP's value don't range beyond that), however `scale_linear()` would work for any range of values so it is more broadly applicable. It would still work if you had values between 50 and 1000 for example while dividing by 100 would not.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation =)

Comment: Thank you for this cool way of editing styles that I wasn´t aware of. But your example works for me only for the simple marker of the layer symbology but it isn´t possible to set the colour of the diagram-boxes in this way or did I get something wrong? For the layer symbology I would have no problem by using rule-based symbologies

Comment: @oppia04 sorry I don't understand your question. How are you histogram boxes set up? Can you edit your question to include a screen shot of the symbology properties please?

Comment: I like to adapt the colour of the histogram bars (see third picture above) instead of the symbology of the features (see your picture). When double klicking on the colour of the histogram there is no way of using rule-based colour or your way of editing colour.

Comment: @oppia04 Sorry I've never used Diagrams in QGIS before, hopefully someone else knows and can help you. It might be worth reposting your question in a different way and specifying that it refers to Diagrams.